# Writing the name of the chapter in the header

Tags: header-footer

Here's what I have written

```
\documentclass{report}
 \usepackage{fancyhdr}
\chapter{Introduction}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\pagestyle{fancyplain}

 \fancyhf{}

\lhead{\fancyplain{}{}}
\rhead{\fancyplain{}{\thepage}}
\end{document}
```

I want to be able to have the name of the chapter on the left header... How can I do that?

Comment: I guess `lhead{\leftmark}` but have not tested it. But there are several issues here, one of the biggest is that `article` class does not provide chapters. You might wanna use `report` instead. Looking at the pagenumbering, you might wanna even use `book`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are simply looking for the following.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\fancyhf{}

\lhead{\leftmark}
%\lhead{\tiny\nouppercase{\leftmark}}% if not to be in all caps and very small
\rhead{\thepage}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Introduction}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\blindtext[20]
\end{document}
```

---

An alternative might be package `scrlayer-scrpage` coming from the KOMA bundle. It is very feature-rich. Content and layout are separated.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[automark,markcase=ignoreuppercase]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\addtokomafont{pagehead}{\upshape\tiny}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Introduction}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\blindtext[20]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Alright! But can't the font be smaller?

Comment: You mean smaller or in noncapital letters CHAPTER vs Chapter ?

Comment: Preferably both please?

Comment: @Selena updated